# Application Crashes every time I run this code

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

Every time i run this code, the app crashes, does anyone know why is this happening. I would really appreciate. Thanks in advance!  The code is quite simple though, I am trying to add a new tab and every time i click a certain button and remove the tab on choosing the current tab.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener {
    TabHost tabs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();


    TabHost.TabSpec spec= tabs.newTabSpec("buttontab");
    spec.setContent(R.id.buttontab);
    spec.setIndicator("Button");
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    Button btn=(Button)tabs.getCurrentView().findViewById(R.id.buttontab);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View view) {
    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return(new AnalogClock(MainActivity.this));
        }
    });
    spec.setIndicator("Clock");
    tabs.addTab(spec);


    //tabs.getTabWidget().removeView(tabs.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3));

    }
        });


  }
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int currentTabNumber = tabs.getCurrentTab();

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "current tab:" +        
currentTabNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
//Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Counts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
tabs.getTabWidget().removeView(tabs.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(currentTabNumbe    r));

}
}
```

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace.

Comment: remove this line  Button btn=(Button)tabs.getCurrentView().findViewById(R.id.buttontab);

Comment: Also you can remove one setContentView.

Comment: Hi you can look into the log file. can you share the error message?

Comment: error log thorws hte following error    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: "error log throws the following error java.lang.NullPointerException" , logcat also states the line where the error is, so you can debug  it properly.

Comment: it shows an error but no message, its kinda strange :/

Comment: show the Log and tell us which line is mentioned there!